# Database error when executing long polling AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, long-polling

Im still learning about long polling with ajax and find few example to do it from this article [here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) and manage code to do it:

```
function poll() {

    var email = 'foo@yahoo.com';

$.ajax({

    type: "post",
    url: "testlongpolling.php",
    data: "email="+email,
    dataType:'json',
    complete: poll, 
    timeout: 30000,
    success: function(result){

        if(/(yes)/.test( result.status ))
        {
            $('#status').html(result.name);
            }
        else
        {
            $('#status').html(result.name);
            }

        } 
    }); 
}
```

But, soon after this code running I had a long list of error messages telling database can not connect:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/ (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewproject\db_connection.php on line 2

After that I can't open phpMyAdmin in my localhost (I have to restart my computer).

Can anyone pointing me to better way to maintain good connection with database for long polling, or how can I clear/stop the ajax call in success callback before ajax timeout runs out and repeating it self?

Any suggestion very much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What does your php file look like? To help us break down the problem.

Comment: This my php code:<?php
include ("db_connection.php");

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$q = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email`='$email'";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$d = mysql_fetch_array($r);

$nt = $d['name'];

if($nt == '')
{
 
 echo 'no';
  
 }
else
{
 
 echo 'yes';
 
 }

?>

Comment: Whats the code for **db_connection.php**, thats where the error seems to be coming from.

Comment: This is my database conection code:<?php
$db_con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456');

mysql_select_db ('DBone');

?>

Answer (score 0):

You should go look in your `httpd.conf` or your `.htaccess` and find a setting called `keepalivetimeout` and set it to `minimum` **not** `maximum`. 
Restart your local server after that. If it does not exist in either of the files, you'll need to add it into there. ([Read More](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout))

Now for your database handling, you should probably use a class like **mysqli** since development for **mysql** is stopping.

```
<?php
// Start new mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Run a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `$email`='$email'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);

// Loop through the data
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo stripslashes($row['username']);
    }
} else {
    echo 'NO RESULTS';
}

// CLOSE CONNECTION
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

?>

Comment: Hi, @dbh thanks for the answer. I manage to find "KeepAliveTimeout" setting in httpd.default.conf but it says i must entering number, not string "minimum". Can you give me what number should I enter?

Comment: @ani have a read of this [Apache httpd.conf KeepAliveTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout)